# Cannot add methods to a list that exists within an enclosing class in Python

Tags: python, list, class, inheritance, methods

Here's my challenge:

I'm working on a game, and I'm trying to keep all of the player/enemy abilities built into methods in order to be more "pythonic" (apologies if I'm misusing the expression).

I'm successfully able to gather a list of methods from a parent class (i.e. "Actor", here) as self.abilities, but I can't add to that same list in a class that inherits "Actor".

I've done some research and I understand that inheritance is tricky, this way, and that there are lots of other ways to get methods affixed to each class, but they mostly seem cumbersome and defeat the purpose of having the classes at all.

Here's a snapshot/example of what I'd like to do:

livingThing --> Actor (can strike/heal) --> Monster (can strike/heal/cast) --> Dragon (can strike/heal/cast/fly) --> etc

I'm trying to avoid reproducing the same list of methods to pull from with every new iteration of the class, and I'm also trying to avoid making *every* object in this game an "Actor".

Because, however, I have the abilities list under **init**, though, I can't seem to access it outside the method.  I currently have Monster and Ally set to simply "pass" just to prove to myself that they -do- inherit the traits of Actor but I can't amend that list from anywhere but within Actor.

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

```
# Anything that can interact directly (take action)
class Player(livingThing):
    def __init__(self,name="The Stranger", HP=10, MP=5, strength=1, intellect=1, spirit=1, luck=5, gil=6):
        self.name = name
        self.HP = HP
        self.MP = MP
        self.gil = gil
        self.strength = strength
        self.intellect = intellect
        self.spirit = spirit
        self.luck = luck

def act(player, enemy):
    actions = {
    "attack" : player.attack, 
    "heal" : player.heal, 
    "flee" : player.flee
    }
    #Takes input from the player
    player.safe = False
    while ((player.HP > 0) and (enemy.HP > 0)) and (player.safe != True):
        decision = input("What would you like to do? ")

        #Sets the user's input as lower-case and checks for it within the dictionary
        if decision.lower() in actions:
            actions[decision.lower()](enemy)
            if player.safe != True:
                enemy.agreact(player)
                player.printHP(enemy)

        else:
            print("That didn't workkkkkk!  Try again.")

# Prints both player and enemy HP
def printHP(player, enemy):
    print("{0}'s' HP: {1} \n{2}'s HP: {3}".format(player.name, player.HP, enemy.name, enemy.HP))

# Allows the player to attack an enemy (currently functional)
def attack(player, enemy):
    enemy.HP -= player.strength
    print("You strike {0} for {1} damage!".format(enemy.name, player.strength))
    #player.printHP(enemy)

# Allows the player to heal a certain amount of health based on its "spirit" stat (currently functional)
def heal(player, enemy):
    healed = randint(0, player.spirit)
    player.HP += healed
    print("You've healed for {0}!".format(healed))
    #player.printHP(enemy)

#Allows the player to attempt to run away
def flee(player, enemy):
    randluck = randint(0, player.luck)
    if randluck > 3:
        print("You successfully escaped!")
        player.safe = True
    else:
        print("You weren't able to escape!")


# Anything that can act with/against the player
class Actor(livingThing):
    def __init__(self, name="Unknown Entity", HP=10, MP=2, strength=1, intellect=1, spirit=3, gil=3):
        self. name = name
        self.HP = HP
        self.MP = MP
        self.gil = gil
        self.strength = strength
        self.intellect = intellect
        self.spirit = spirit
        self.abilities = [self.strike, self.heal]
        def printabilities():
            print(self.abilities)

    # Chooses how your opponent will respond to your attack
    def agreact(self, player):
        choice = randint(0, len(self.abilities)-1)
        self.abilities[choice](player)

    # A basic "hit back" reaction from your opponent--everyone can do this
    def strike(self, player):
        player.HP -= self.strength
        print("{0} hit {1} for {2}!".format(self.name, player.name, self.strength))

    def heal(self, enemy):
        healed = randint(0, self.spirit)
        self.HP += healed
        print("{0} healed for {1}!".format(self.name, healed))



class Monster(Actor):
    pass

class Ally(Actor):
    pass
```

Comment: *"I can't amend that list from anywhere but within Actor."*: **Why** do you think so? Doing `class Monster(...`, `def __init__(...`, `super().__init__()`, `self.abilities.append(self.cast)` should work.

Comment: @stovfl Thanks for your response.  I'm having a little trouble getting that to work; I'm a little perplexed as to what fits where.  Does "super().__init__()" need to be an argument within __init__?  Is it part of the method __init__?  Or is it an independent, entirely separate method?  Also, to successfully integrate the new method "cast", would I define that method within "super"/init or within "init"?  Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind--I've got it working and it seems to perform just as intended!  Thank you!

Comment: Read [`super([type[, object-or-type]])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)